# Use \nopagebreak (or similar) in supertabular

Tags: page-breaking, longtable, counters, supertabular

I'm trying to add multipages tabulars with counters in tabular tail. I first tried *longtable* but as it generates head and tail before the table content I can't use counters. So I used *supertable* who handle this very well. But I also want to control the breaking of this table as lines works by groups which are not breakable (as much as possible). I tried *\nopagebreak*, *\\** but none seems to work in *supertabular* environnement.

Here an example where I want that my 2-lines groups not to be breakable :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \newcounter{MyCounter}

    \lipsum[1]

    \tablehead{
        \hline
        \normalsize\textbf{\uppercase{Name}} & \normalsize\textbf{\uppercase{Qty}} \\
    }

    \tabletail{
        \hline
        \textbf{\uppercase{Total}} & \arabic{MyCounter} \\
        \hline
    }

    \begin{supertabular}{|l|c|}
        %% This part is repeated X times and is not breakable
        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\
    \end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

So my question how can't I get counters and page break control on multipage tables?

Thanks.

EDIT : My real document to ease support.
    \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

```
    \usepackage{helvet}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[francais]{babel}
    \usepackage[margin=0.5cm,headheight=7.7cm,headsep=0.5cm,includehead,includefoot]{geometry} %pas par defaut
    \usepackage{fancyhdr} %pas par defaut
    \usepackage{lastpage} %pas par defaut
    \usepackage{array} %pas par defaut?
    \usepackage{multirow} %pas par defaut
    \usepackage[draft]{graphicx} %pas par defaut
    \usepackage{eurosym} %pas par defaut
    \usepackage[breakwords]{truncate} %pas par d?aut
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor} %pas par defaut
    \usepackage{supertabular} %pas par defaut

    \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

    \pagestyle{fancy}

    \fancyhead[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all headers
    \fancyhead[C]{
    \begin{tabular*}{20cm}{p{3.2cm}p{3.2cm}p{4.2cm}p{3.2cm}p{3.2cm}}
    \multicolumn{1}{l} {
    \begin{tabular}{l}
    \large\textbf{Client name} \\
    \footnotesize{Client addr}\\
    \footnotesize{ZIPCode City}\\
    \end{tabular}
    } & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\multirow{3}[2]{*}{
    \includegraphics[width=4.8cm,height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{path/img.ext}
    }} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{
    \begin{tabular}{r}
    \uppercase{FACTURE : invoiceNumber} \\
    \uppercase{DU : date}
    \end{tabular}
    } \\
    & & & & \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{
    \begin{tabular}{l}
    \footnotesize{somedata de value\euro} \\
    \footnotesize{TVA INTRA : administrationdata}\\
    \footnotesize{Code APE : administrationdata}
    \end{tabular}
    } & & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\multirow{4}[20]{*}{
    \begin{tabular}{c}
    \includegraphics[width=6.4cm,height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{\detokenize{path/img.ext}}
    \end{tabular}
    }} & \\
    & & & & \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{
    \begin{tabular}{l}
    \large\textbf{Facturé à:}
    \end{tabular}
    } & & & & \\
    & & & & \\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{
    \begin{tabular}{l}
    \textbf{\uppercase{company name}} \\
    \small\uppercase{company addr} \\
    \small{ZIPCode City}
    \end{tabular}
    } & \multicolumn{3}{l}{
    \begin{tabular}{l}
    \small{\textbf{Pour tout courrier : }}\\
    \small{Company name addr} \\
    \small{ZIPCode City}
    \end{tabular}
    } \\
    & & & & \\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}
    {
    \begin{tabular}{l}
    \textbf{CIP :} uniqID \\
    \\
    \textbf{Compte débiteur :} bank account data
    \end{tabular}
    } & \multicolumn{3}{l}
    {
    \begin{tabular}{l}
    \small{\textbf{En cas de retour de marchandise : }}\\
    \small{Company name addr} \\
    \small{ZIPCode city}
    \end{tabular}
    }
    \end{tabular*}
    }

    \fancyfoot[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all footers
    \fancyfoot[C]{
    \textbf{Page \thepage /\pageref{LastPage}}
    }

    \begin{document}
    \tablehead{
    \hline
    \cellcolor{black} & \cellcolor{black} & \cellcolor{black} & \cellcolor{black} & \cellcolor{black} & \cellcolor{black} & \cellcolor{black} \\
    \cellcolor{black} & \cellcolor{black}\normalsize\color{white}\textbf{P.U.} & \cellcolor{black} & \cellcolor{black} & \cellcolor{black}\normalsize\color{white}\textbf{P.U. net} &
    \cellcolor{black}\normalsize\color{white}\textbf{Montant} & \cellcolor{black}\normalsize\color{white}\textbf{TVA} \\
    \multirow{-2}{*}{
    \cellcolor{black}\normalsize\color{white}\textbf{Désignation}
    } & \cellcolor{black}\normalsize\color{white}\textbf{Catalogue} & \multirow{-2}{*}{
    \cellcolor{black}\normalsize\color{white}\textbf{Remise}
    } & \normalsize\multirow{-2}{*}{
    \cellcolor{black}\normalsize\color{white}\textbf{Qté}
    } & \cellcolor{black}\normalsize\color{white}\textbf{H.T. (\euro)} & \cellcolor{black}\normalsize\color{white}\textbf{H.T. (\euro)} & \cellcolor{black}\color{white}\normalsize\textbf{(\%)} \\
    }

    \tabletail{
    \hline
    }

    \scriptsize{
    \noindent\begin{supertabular}{|p{9.7cm}|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
     & & & & & & \\
    % Non-breakable repeated part
    \small\textbf{Bon de commande : deliveryOrderNumber} & & & & & & \\
    % Random times repeated sub-part
    \truncate{10cm}{
        \small{~~~~someText. long description}} & \small{price} & \small{discount} & \small{qty} & \small{price dis.} & \small{total} & \small{VAT} \\
    % End subpart
     & & & & & & \\
    % End part
    \end{supertabular}
    }

    \footnotesize{Some long and boring legal notices.}

    \noindent\normalsize\begin{tabular}{p{10cm}r}
    \begin{tabular}{l}
    \small{Facture n\degre{}invoiceNUmber établie par le mandataire CompanyName}\\
    \small{au nom et pour le compte de CompanyName}\\
    \\
    \small{échéance : date~~~~~montant total TTC : full price} \\
    \\
    \small{\textbf{Modalité de paiement :}} \\
    \small{Réglement par LCR directe au date}\\
    \small{\textbf{Nom du compte :} AccountName}\\
    \small{\textbf{Numéro : } AccountNumpber}
    \end{tabular}
    &
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{6pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    montant HT & TVA & montant TVA & NET A PAYER \\
    \hline
    Tot(ex. VAT)\euro & VAT\% & VAT total\euro & Tot (incl. VAT)\euro \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{Total NET à payer} & Tot. (incl. VAT)\euro \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the goal height of the tabular before the problematic line. This will force an earlier page break:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \newcounter{MyCounter}

    \lipsum[1]

    \tablehead{
        \hline
        \normalsize\textbf{\uppercase{Name}} & \normalsize\textbf{\uppercase{Qty}} \\
    }

    \tabletail{
        \hline
        \textbf{\uppercase{Total}} & \arabic{MyCounter} \\
        \hline
    }

    \begin{supertabular}{|l|c|}
        %% This part is repeated X times and is not breakable
        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\
        \hline\shrinkheight{-\normalbaselineskip} 
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\\shrinkheight{\normalbaselineskip} 
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\

        \hline
        \addtocounter{MyCounter}{4} MyLabel & 4 \\
        SubLabel & \\
    \end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I forgot to say that I don't know on which line it will break because the repeated content has various number of lines and the content before the supertabular is also dynamic.

Comment: Well then add the two \shrinkheight everywhere.

Comment: It works well on my MWE but not in my real document. It breaks the page too early and even on line that I don't want it to break. I will edit my original question to post my template for better support.